# Is using zlib (or similar) compression worth/recommended when transmitting JPEG-compressed screen tiles over network (remote screencasting app)?

Tags: c++, zlib, vnc, libjpeg

I'm starting to implement some sort of remote screencasting (VNC-alike) client/server software in C++ (Windows platform), which just transmits the screen updates (image tiles) over the network.

The screen is divided in blocks and each tile is compressed into JPEG (probably I'll use libjpeg-turbo), before sending over network. So my question is, will it be good to implement another layer of compression (lossless) for these (already-JPEG-compressed) tiles, e.g. using zlib?

I have a feeling that zlib won't give any significant improvement in terms of bandwidth as the JPEG files will be already compressed. I'd like to avoid further time and money investment for implementing additional compression layer just for testing purposes, so I'd like to hear your suggestions.

P.S.: As a side question, are there any better alternatives than encoding tiles into JPEG? Maybe lossless compression right away? Is the above-mentioned technique (dividing screen into tiles => selecting updated tiles => compressing them into JPEG => sending over network) good way to implement such software?

Any kind of input would be much appreciated!

Comment: You're unlikely to squeeze additional compression out of JPEG compressed tiles (if for no other reason, then because otherwise JPEG would be quite poor as compressor). The transformed, quantized JPEG data is already compressed (usually with a huffman encoding). Also, you can only expect reasonable compression from LZ given a good amount of data. Since you have "tiles", the data will be small.

Comment: **Got it, thanks everybody for your answers.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely unneccessary.

Better option is to use both methods: count the colors in the block and use zlib/rle/etc for few colors and jpeg for many. That's the very basic approach. I recommend you to take a look at the Remote Framebuffer Protocol of the VNC.

Comment: Vladimir, when you say: "count the colors in the block and use zlib/rle/etc for few colors and jpeg for many", what will this give me? Will this technique save bandwidth, or CPU, or picture quality (because of lossless compression)? Or will it require more of some of the resources (bandwidth or CPU)? In other words, what's the trade-off in such case? Thanks

Comment: This approach allows to losslessly compress UI object like windows and fonts while keeping the bitrate low if there is a photo/video content on the screen. So the overall picture quality remains high in exchange for the CPU cycles.

Comment: Not sure about what you mean exactly, but I assume it does not improve bandwidth nor CPU performance, only the picture quality for some regions.

Answer (score 3):

JPEG files are already compressed nearly as small as they can be. You might save a few bytes on the header, but that may be overcome by the overhead of the additional compression.

If you need to do a quick check just to prove the point, it should be easy to zip up a collection of sample jpeg files and see what the difference is.